# Google 360degree StreetView like effect in Android

Tags: android, animation, android-ndk, image-rotation, 360-panorama

I am not sure how to achieve an effect like Google's 360 degree StreetView in Android. I have even came across the similar features in commonfloor's app. It has a 360 degree panaromic effect as shown in the link - [CommonFloor's Live Tour](https://www.commonfloor.com/?f=sem_CF-BKEM-07&gclid=CJyZ4bOn98wCFdMPaAodRygK0Q)

I have researched about this and couldn't find much resources. I am not even sure where should I start from? Are there any libraries already available for the same? 
Found a library [PanaromaGl](https://github.com/zarelaky/panoramagl-android) but it has not been maintained since 2 years. Are there any alternatives before I decide to go for this library?

Thank you in advance